# Is there any Newrelic plugin or agent to monitor Unicorn?

Tags: unicorn, newrelic

Can we monitor Unicorn with New Relic? Whether it is down , and if possible any more details available.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Unicorn plugin listed in plugin central. It is written by DianthuDia and here is the information for it:

Description

Report Unicorn idle worker ratio & memory usage to NewRelic.

Requirements

Ruby 2.0 or greater.

Installation

1. Download the latest tagged version from https://github.com/DianthuDia/newrelic_unicorn_plugin/tags
2. Extract to the location you want to run the unicorn agent from
3. Copy config/template_newrelic_plugin.yml to config/newrelic_plugin.yml
4. Edit config/newrelic_plugin.yml and replace "YOUR_LICENSE_KEY_HERE"
5. run bundle install
6. run bin/newrelic_unicorn_agent